# Make generic definition optional in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift4

My class definition looks like

```
class Response<T : Decodable> {
    var responseData : T?
}

class Test {
    func someFunction() {
        let serverResponse = Response<Employee>();
        let errorResponse = Response(); //Compilation error here
    }
}
```

How I can make the Response class to be initialized either through a Decodable class or nil representation?

Comment: A generic type must specify what the placeholder type is when you declare the variable (or provide enough information where it could be inferred). One solution is to wrap it an enum (like Alamofire's [`Result`](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Enums/Result.html) type). But that still requires you to know what the response type was going to be, e.g. I was requesting an employee, but there was an error. Or do you really not know what type you were expecting when the error occurred?

Answer (score 3):

Response is usually written like this:

```
enum Response<T : Decodable> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}
```